# Class not storing Vector values

Tags: c++, oop

The issue I am having is that I am storing values into my vectors and concatenating them into one bundle of vectors. However, when I go back into the class where I stored the values, they are gone. VS then throws up a generic error. Please find my code below.

```
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
void Train_Time_Entries();

struct
{
    int iOption, iCount = 0;
    int myContNo = -1;
    int fDecide = -1;
    string AdminUser, AdminPass;
    vector <string> AdminUsers{ "John1966", "Christine55", "BlakeBennett74", "SarahHarding93", "Connor1987" };
    vector <string> AdminPasswords{ "KalEL", "HenryDog6", "WesternRailway21", "Railwayssince89", "Budweisersaregood" };
    vector <string> sAdmins;
    string sLocation, sArrive, sDepart, sDay;
    bool bAdmin = true, bAddEnt = true, bMenu = true, bMenu1 = true;

}iop, admus, admpa, AdminUsers, AdminPas, bAdm, sLoc, sArr, sDep, bAdd, myCo,fde, bMe, bMen, sAds,sDa,iCou;

//****************Admin Only********************
class Train_Time_Ent
{
public:
    vector<string> sLocations;
    vector<string> sDay;
    vector<string> sArrive;
    vector<string> sDepart;
    vector<string> sBundle;
};

//*****************Admin Only*******************
void Train_Time_Entries() 
{
    system("cls");
    Train_Time_Ent myobjs;

    do
    {
        cout << "           Train Entries(Admin View Only)\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Please enter a train location: " << flush;
            getline(cin, sLoc.sLocation);

            myobjs.sLocations.push_back(sLoc.sLocation + "\n");

            cout << "Enter a day of the week for times: " << flush;
            cin >> sDa.sDay;

            myobjs.sDay.push_back(sDa.sDay + "\n");

            do
            {
                cout << "Now enter a Train Arrive time for this location: " << flush;
                cin >> sArr.sArrive;

                myobjs.sArrive.push_back(sArr.sArrive + "\n");

                cout << "Would you like to add any more arrival times? Y=1 N=2: " << flush;
                cin >> iop.iOption;

                if (iop.iOption == 2)
                {
                    cout << "Okay Thank you\n";
                    break;
                }

            } while (iop.iOption == 1);
            
            do
            {
                cout << "Now enter a Train Departure time for this location: " << flush;
                cin >> sDep.sDepart;

                myobjs.sDepart.push_back(sDep.sDepart + "\n");

                cout << "Would you like to enter more departure times? Y=1 N=2: " << flush;
                cin >> iop.iOption;

                if (iop.iOption == 2)
                {
                    cout << "Okay Thank you\n";
                    break;
                }
            } while (iop.iOption == 1);

            cout << "Would you like to make any other entries? Y = 1 N = 2: " << flush;
            cin.ignore();
            cin >> iop.iOption;

            if (iop.iOption == 1)
            {
                bAdd.bAddEnt = true;
                fde.fDecide++;
            }
            else if (iop.iOption == 2)
            {
                bAdd.bAddEnt = false;
                fde.fDecide++;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (bAdd.bAddEnt == true);

    // For future entries this needs to be checked so the values are set accordingly
    for (int i = myCo.myContNo; myCo.myContNo <= fde.fDecide;)
    {
        myCo.myContNo++;
        if (myCo.myContNo <= fde.fDecide)
        {
            myobjs.sBundle.push_back(myobjs.sDay[myCo.myContNo] + myobjs.sLocations[myCo.myContNo] + myobjs.sArrive[myCo.myContNo] + myobjs.sDepart[myCo.myContNo]);
        }
    }

    cout << myobjs.sBundle[0];
    myCo.myContNo--;
    bMe.bMenu = true;
    cout << "Exiting to Admin Menu...\n";
    _getch();

    
}
void Concatenate_Admins()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < AdminUsers.AdminUsers.size(); i++)
    {
        sAds.sAdmins.push_back(AdminUsers.AdminUsers[i] + AdminPas.AdminPasswords[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "               Western Railway\n";
        cout << "Please choose from one of the following\n";
        cout << "1:: Train Times\n";
        cout << "2:: Make a Reservation\n";
        cout << "3:: Make a Cancellation\n";
        cout << "4:: Reserved Trains\n";
        cout << "5:: Admin Login\n";
        cout << "6:: Quit\n";
        cin >> iop.iOption;

        switch (iop.iOption)
        {
        case 1: 
            iop.iOption = 1;
            //Train_Times();
        case 2:
            iop.iOption = 2;
            //Make_A_Reservation();
        case 3:
            iop.iOption = 3;
            //Make_A_Cancellation();
        case 4:
            iop.iOption = 4;
            //Reserved_Trains();

        case 5:
            iop.iOption = 5;
            Concatenate_Admins();
            // Look into an option to add more admin logins after authorization of login (New Employees)
            // also look into updating times for various locations
            do
            {
                system("cls");
                cout << "       *******Admin Login*******\n";
                cout << "Please enter Authorised credentials below;\n";
                cout << "Username: " << flush;
                cin >> admus.AdminUser;
                cout << "Password: " << flush;
                cin >> admpa.AdminPass;

                iCou.iCount++;
                if (find(sAds.sAdmins.begin(), sAds.sAdmins.end(), admus.AdminUser + admpa.AdminPass) != sAds.sAdmins.end())
                {
                    cout << "Successfully Logged in...\n";
                    bAdm.bAdmin = false;
                }
                else if (find(sAds.sAdmins.begin(), sAds.sAdmins.end(), admus.AdminUser + admpa.AdminPass) == sAds.sAdmins.end())
                {
                    cout << "Entry not recognized...\n";
                    cout << "No " << iCou.iCount << " of 3 Attempts\n";
                    bAdm.bAdmin = true;

                    if (iCou.iCount == 3)
                    {
                        cout << "Too many attempts made\n";
                        cout << "Exiting to main menu...\n";
                        bAdm.bAdmin = false;
                    }
                }
                _getch();

            } while (bAdm.bAdmin == true);

            do
            {
                if (iCou.iCount <= 3)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "       *******Admin Mode*******\n";
                    cout << "Please choose from one of the following; \n";
                    cout << "Option 1: Train Time Entries\n";
                    cout << "Option 2: View Reserved Lists\n";
                    cout << "Option 3: View Passenger Info\n";
                    cout << "Option 4: Return to main menu\n";
                    cin >> iop.iOption;

                    switch (iop.iOption)
                    {
                    case 1:
                        iop.iOption = 1;
                        Train_Time_Entries();
                        bMe.bMenu = true;
                    case 2:
                        iop.iOption = 2;
                        //Reserved_Lists();
                        bMe.bMenu = true;
                    case 3:
                        iop.iOption = 3;
                        //Passenger_Info();
                        bMe.bMenu = true;
                    case 4:
                        iop.iOption = 4;
                        cout << "Returning to Main Menu...\n";
                        bMe.bMenu = false;
                        break;
                        _getch();
                    }
                }
                else if (iCou.iCount > 3)
                {
                    bMen.bMenu1 = true;
                    main();
                }
            } while (bMe.bMenu == true);

            bMen.bMenu1 = true;
            break;

        case 6:
            iop.iOption = 6;
            cout << "Exiting Application...\n";
            bMen.bMenu1 = false;
            break;
        }
    } while (bMen.bMenu1 == true);

    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Please try to make a [mre]. There's considerably more code here than is necessary to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Do you have some actual steps we can follow that creates the problems you are having?

Comment: Specifically this section of code has an issue when i come around to adding more values to the vectors;   for (int i = myCo.myContNo; myCo.myContNo <= fde.fDecide;)
    {
        myCo.myContNo++;
        if (myCo.myContNo <= fde.fDecide)
        {
            myobjs.sBundle.push_back(myobjs.sDay[myCo.myContNo] + myobjs.sLocations[myCo.myContNo] + myobjs.sArrive[myCo.myContNo] + myobjs.sDepart[myCo.myContNo]);
        }
    }

Comment: by all means copy and paste my code into visual studio, log into the admin section with one of the authorized logins and make an entry. exit the admin menu into the main menu then repeat the process, the error will soon show up after this.

Comment: i have since realised that voids dont store value, therefor if i were to paste the code from "Admin Only" into main the code would retain.

Comment: i guess i like to keep my code modular.